# Backup on S3 using EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, backup

I would like to backup my web server data on S3. My idea is to fire up an EC2 instance twice a day, pull data from the web server (which is not on amazon), store it on S3 and shutdown.

I would not like to push the backup from my webserver to S3 directly, because I prefer using rsync and I don't want to store s3 details on the webserver.

I'm new to AWS, so my questions are:

- does this seem a good solution?
- if I shutdown my EC2 instance will it persist data (configuration)?
- what is a good way of mounting S3 as filesystem on EC2?

Answer (score 3):

Firing up an EC2 instance just to do the sync seems a bit over the top -- any machine would be enough. The data you add to the EC2 instance will not be saved unless you use EBS for your root disk or create a new machine image that contains the configuration.

As for the actual sync, have a look at [s3sync](https://github.com/ms4720/s3sync) or [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/).

Answer (score 0):

> 1) does this seem a good solution?

It seems like an overkill to use an EC2 - but if you want, you can use a micro instance or even spot instance to lower your overhead. Otherwise, a cheap [vps](http://bhost.net/) or even [mini vps](https://clients.inceptionhosting.com/cart.php?gid=13) at **EUR3/yr** would suffice.

> 2) if I shutdown my EC2 instance will it persist data (configuration)?

Yes. So long you stop your instance (instead of terminating). If you want a persistent IP address, you can use Amazon Eleastic IP - comes free (but limited) with EC2.

> 3) what is a good way of mounting S3 as filesystem on EC2?

I would think mounting your S3 directing on your first web server would suffice. But since you did mention you didn't want any S3 details on your webserver (although you could place sensitive details outside your apache container), [s3f3](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) would be suitable for this case. The moment you launch your instance, the auto-mount that you would have set up will synchronize your instance with S3 automatically. Otherwise, you can also choose to do so via cron job - but that would require more scripting.